# How to center more label texts that are under eachother into one center?

Tags: c#, wpf

The purple line is the center

[image]

I want to center text of multiple labels into one, as shown in image. The purple line is "The center".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a StackPanel with a vertical orientation and then horizontally center all of the child content:

```
<StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
    <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">Test</Label>
    <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">Testtete1</Label>
    <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Center">HelloTe</Label>
</StackPanel>
```